# Why returns different results in NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 and Intel® Core i5-9300H in OpenCL + Rust?

Tags: rust, parallel-processing, opencl

I am trying to figure out why I am getting this discrepancy of results between GPU and CPU, I have also confirmed that in a virtual macOS I had the exact same thing is happening, I am attaching code snippet and input and output values:

```rust
/// The kernel to use
const OPENCL_PROGRAM: &'static str = r#"
__kernel void initialize_algorithm_buffers(__global float *result, __global float *distance, __global int *visited) {
    // Get the global id based on count of vertexs and assigned for thread
    int gid = get_global_id(0);

    // Initialize the buffers in parallel
    if (gid == 0) {
        distance[gid] = 0;
        visited[gid] = 1;
        result[gid] = 0;
    } else {
        distance[gid] = 0;
        visited[gid] = 0;
        result[gid] = FLT_MAX;
    }
}

__kernel void shortest_path_algorithm(__global float *result, __global float *matrix, __global float *distance, __global int *visited, int vertex_count) {
    // Get the global id based on count of vertexs and assigned for thread
    int gid = get_global_id(0);

    // Validate if the vertex is not visited
    if (visited[gid] != 1) {
        // Mark the vertex as visited
        visited[gid] = 1;

        // Get the start edge
        for(int edge = 0; edge < vertex_count; edge++) {
            // Get the edge from adjacent matrix
            float weight = matrix[gid * vertex_count + edge];

            // Validate if the edge is valid
            if (weight != 0.0f && weight != FLT_MAX) {
                // Get the distance
                float dist = distance[edge] + weight;

                // Get the result
                if (distance[gid] == 0.0 || distance[gid] > dist) {
                    distance[gid] = dist;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

__kernel void merge_sortest_path(__global float *result, __global float *distance, __global int *visited) {
    // Get the global id based on count of vertexs and assigned for thread
    int gid = get_global_id(0);

    // Get the result
    if (result[gid] > distance[gid]) {
        result[gid] = distance[gid];
    }

    // Reset the visited flag
    if (gid != 0) {
        visited[gid] = 0;
    }
}
"#;

/// The sortest path service
///
/// # Fields
///
/// * `device` - The device to use
/// * `context` - The context to use
/// * `program` - The program to use
/// * `queue` - The queue to use
///
pub struct SortestPath {
    queue: Queue,
    device: Device,
    context: Context,
    program: Program,
}

impl SortestPath {
    /// Create a new instance of the walker
    ///
    /// # Returns
    ///
    /// * `Walker` - The walker object
    ///
    pub fn new() -> SortestPath {
        // Get the default platform
        let platform = Platform::default();

        // Print the initialization info
        trace!("Initializing OpenCL components before operations...");
        info!("Using platform: {}", platform.name().unwrap());

        // Prepare OpenCL Elements
        let device = Device::first(platform).unwrap();
        let context = Context::builder().devices(device).build().unwrap();
        let queue = Queue::new(&context, device, None).unwrap();
        let program = Program::builder()
            .src(OPENCL_PROGRAM).devices(device)
            .build(&context).unwrap();

        // Print the device info and start operations
        trace!("Initialized OpenCL components, starting operations...");
        info!("Using device: {}", device.name().unwrap());

        // Build the object for the service
        SortestPath { device, context, program, queue }
    }
}

impl SortestPath {
    /// Process the kernel result
    ///
    /// This method will process the result of the kernel and return the result
    /// of the operation.
    ///
    /// # Arguments
    ///
    /// * `result` - The result of the kernel
    /// * `lambda` - The lambda to execute if the result is ok
    ///
    /// # Returns
    ///
    /// * `Result<Vec<f32>>` - The result of the operation
    ///
    fn process_kernel_result(&self, result: Result<()>, lambda: impl FnOnce() -> Result<Vec<f32>>) -> Result<Vec<f32>> {
        match result {
            Ok(_) => lambda(),
            Err(e) => {
                // Print the error in console
                error!("Critical error occurred in kernel: {}", e.api_status().unwrap().to_string());

                // Return error code
                return Err(e);
            }
        }
    }

    /// Returns the best path for hamiltonian walk
    ///
    /// This method will return the best path for the hamiltonian walk
    /// enumerating elements in step order over the vector result.
    ///
    /// # Arguments
    ///
    /// * `matrix` - The matrix to walk
    ///
    /// # Returns
    ///
    /// * `Vec<i32>` - The path of the walk
    ///
    pub fn get_sortest_path(&self, matrix: Matrix) -> Result<Vec<f32>> {
        // Print the initialization
        trace!("Initializing buffers for the kernel...");

        // Instantiate result matrix
        let result_buffer = Buffer::<f32>::builder()
            .queue(self.queue.clone())
            .len(matrix.width).build().unwrap();

        // Instantiate the matrix as buffer
        let matrix_buffer = Buffer::<f32>::builder()
            .len(matrix.data.len()).queue(self.queue.clone())
            .copy_host_slice(&matrix.data)
            .build().unwrap();

        // Instantiate path matrix
        let distance_buffer = Buffer::<f32>::builder()
            .queue(self.queue.clone())
            .len(matrix.width).build().unwrap();

        let visited_buffer = Buffer::<i32>::builder()
            .queue(self.queue.clone())
            .len(matrix.width).build().unwrap();

        // Print the buffers initialization
        trace!("Buffers initialized, starting kernel...");

        // Instantiate the buffers kernel
        let initialize_algorithm_buffers = Kernel::builder()
            .program(&self.program).queue(self.queue.clone())
            .name("initialize_algorithm_buffers").global_work_size(SpatialDims::One((matrix.width) as usize))
            .arg(&result_buffer).arg(&distance_buffer).arg(&visited_buffer)
            .build().unwrap();

        // Instantiate the main kernel
        let shortest_path_algorithm = Kernel::builder()
            .program(&self.program).queue(self.queue.clone())
            .name("shortest_path_algorithm").global_work_size(SpatialDims::One((matrix.width) as usize))
            .arg(&result_buffer).arg(&matrix_buffer).arg(&distance_buffer).arg(&visited_buffer).arg(matrix.width as i32)
            .build().unwrap();

        // Instantiate the merge kernel
        let merge_sortest_path = Kernel::builder()
            .program(&self.program).queue(self.queue.clone())
            .name("merge_sortest_path").global_work_size(SpatialDims::One((matrix.width) as usize))
            .arg(&result_buffer).arg(&distance_buffer).arg(&visited_buffer)
            .build().unwrap();

        // Print the kernel start
        trace!("Kernel started, enqueueing the operation...");

        // Instantiate the result
        let mut result = vec![0.0; matrix.width];

        // Run the program and wait for it to finish
        unsafe {
            self.process_kernel_result(initialize_algorithm_buffers.enq(), || {
                // Run the algorithm
                for _ in 0..matrix.width {
                    self.process_kernel_result(shortest_path_algorithm.enq(), || {
                        self.process_kernel_result(merge_sortest_path.enq(), || {
                            // Print the end of the operation
                            trace!("The iteration was successfully completed! Preparing the return of result...");

                            // Copy the results to the host
                            result_buffer.read(&mut result).enq()?;
                            trace!("Result: {:?}", result);

                            // Return dummy result
                            Ok(vec![0.0; 1])
                        })
                    }).expect("Error while merging the sortest path");
                }

                // Return the result
                Ok(result)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The entry value is:

```json
{
    "data": [
    1, 4,  2, 0,  0, 0,
    4, 1,  1, 5,  0, 0,
    2, 1,  1, 8, 10, 0, 
    0, 5,  8, 1,  2, 6,
    0, 0, 10, 2,  1, 2,
    0, 0,  0, 6,  2, 1
     ],
    "width": 6,
    "height": 6
}
```

And the respective outputs is:

- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050:  `[0.0, 3.0, 2.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0]`
- Intel® Core i5-9300H: `[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 4.0]`

As far as I have been validating, the results returned by NVIDIA's OpenCL are correct, but the rest of the OpenCL driver implementations return the value returned by the Intel CPU. Why is this happening? Did I forget to initialize something?

Comment: Sounds like it's time for more debugging. Who can say without really digging in here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I did not correctly take into account how the OpenCL concurrency model works globally. I was reading from the temporary vector which was in turn rewriting other workers, this was causing serious inconsistency problems in the output. Rewriting the part of the affected program to work in read mode with the output vector seems to correctly resolve the issue.

I leave here a code snippet for anyone who might be interested:

```c
        // Get the start edge
        for(int edge = 0; edge < vertex_count; edge++) {
            // Get the edge from adjacent matrix
            float weight = matrix[gid * vertex_count + edge];

            // Validate if the edge is valid
            if (weight != 0.0f && weight != FLT_MAX) {
                // Get the distance
                float dist = result[edge] + weight;

                // Get the result
                if (distance[gid] == 0.0 || result[gid] > dist) {
                    distance[gid] = dist;
                }
            }
        }
```

If we notice, the only thing that has changed is the exclusive use of the vector `distance` for the hybrid use of `distance` and `result`.